# IOS - LED Strobe Flashlight Slider iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, led, flashlight

Hi i am making a flashlight app in Objective C for iPhones, i have got some basic features such as an LED dimming slider and a button to turn the flashlight on and off but i wanted to add a second slider to add a strobe light effect where sliding the slider would increase the frequency of the flashes.

I have tried anything i can think of and nothing is working :/

This is part of the code i am using for it:

```
-(IBAction)torchOn:(id)sender;
{


onButton.hidden = YES;
offButton.hidden = NO;
onView.hidden = NO;
offView.hidden = YES;

if([self.flashlight isTorchAvailable] && [self.flashlight isTorchModeSupported:AVCaptureTorchModeOn])
{
    BOOL success = [self.flashlight lockForConfiguration:nil];
    if (success)
    {
        [self.flashlight setTorchMode:(AVCaptureTorchModeOn)];
        [self.flashlight unlockForConfiguration];
    }
  }
}


- (IBAction)intensitySliderValueChanged:(UISlider*)sender {
if(sender.value == 0 || sender.value > 1) return;

if([self.flashlight isTorchAvailable] && [self.flashlight isTorchModeSupported:AVCaptureTorchModeOn])
{
    BOOL success = [self.flashlight lockForConfiguration:nil];
    if (success)
    {

        [self.flashlight setTorchModeOnWithLevel:sender.value error:nil];
        [self.flashlight unlockForConfiguration];
    }
  }
}
```

I know this is not particularly useful in understanding my problem but if any of you have a solution i would be extremely grateful!

Comment: You should post the code where you strobe the light.

Comment: I haven't done it yet because i have no idea how to, do you know?

Comment: Post the code that you have tried that is not working strobing the light.

Comment: The question is why build a flashlight when it freely comes with iOS 7? One may ponder upon that question for a long time, or until your app gets rejected by review team.

Comment: do you think it will get rejected because they already have one? its just i don't like using control centre and this one is more featured